# jQuery Tab not rendered

Tags: jquery

I have below JSP code which need to show jQuery Tab (i.e. Login and Register tabs), but currently the JSP does not show the tab (the URL of the JSP screen as attached below, as I am not able to attach picture as below 10 reputation).

I have imported the css and jQuery files into Eclipse webapp\css and webapp\js folder as per below project structure and there are lot of errors in the webapp\css\jquery-ui.css script after importing.  Find out through internet that the errors in the css can be ignored, is my understanding correct ?  If yes, would like to get advice on why the Tab not shown ?  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login and Registration Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="login">
                    <% if((String)session.getAttribute("error") != null){ %>
                    <h4> Invalid Email or Password. Please try again.</h4>
                    <% } %>
                    <form method="post" action="LoginController">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label> 
                        <br /> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> 
                        <br /> <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <br /> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> <br />
                        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="register">
                    <% if((String)session.getAttribute("errorReg") != null){ %>
                    <h4><%=session.getAttribute("errorReg") %></h4>
                    <% } %>
                    <form method="post" action="RegistrationController">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                          <br /> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> 
                          <br /> <label for="email">Email:</label>
                          <br /> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> 
                          <br /> <label for="password">Password:</label>
                          <br /> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> 
                          <br /> <label for="address">Address:</label>
                          <br /> <input type="text" name="address" id="address" /> 
                          <br /> 
                          <br /> <input type="submit" value="Register">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
 
.wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
 
.container {
    min-height: 400px;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

***Edited***

I have used Firefox to view page source and find out that there is below resource not found error when I click on the .js link in the page source file, seem it is file path error of the jquery script (while css link is fine).  I have refer to other topic in this forum and verified that the js files path and folder are correctly specified as per below.  Need advice on what could be the cause ?  Thanks in advance

**Resource files location:**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

**File Structure of the jQuery files in Eclipse project:**

--webapp/resources/css/jquery-ui.css  (version v1.11.4)

--webapp/resources/css/style.css (code as shown below)

--webapp/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.js

--webapp/resources/js/jquery-ui.js (version v1.11.4)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

***Final Resolution***

1) Resolved "No mapping found for HTTP request, 
/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.js" error, after placed the jquery files in resources folder instead of Eclipse webapps folder (as shown above).

2) Resolved below js files not found in browser, due to js folder was wrongly named as "jss", thus have renamed it to "js".

**Error found when click the js link in the Firefox view page source**

> Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 - Error
>   report
>
> ## 525D76;}-->
>
> ## HTTP Status 404 -
>
> **type** Status
>
> report
>
> **message**
>
> **description** The
>   requested resource is not available.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/6.0.37

***URL of JSP screen in browser***

http://postimg.org/image/qi52vc89p/

Comment: can you post console error if there are any?

Comment: can you check the browser console... also share the generated html

Comment: There is no error in the browser screen. The JSP screen that not show tab as shown in the attached URL in the question. Can share how to check the browser console? Besides, I just find out that there are errors in the TOMCAT server console (as attached in question) when visit the JSP page (i.e. page returned from controller) but why the URL shown in the error contains the css and js file name, which is not my JSP URL?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running you code and I am able to see the tabs doubt is only in your jquery-ui.css please replace with below and try

```
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-  ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I have tried with above, still encountered the error shown in the command prompt of the TOMCAT server, and tabs not shown as well.  The TOMCAT error and JSP screen (URL link) as posted in question.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry then I trien in asp server and it worked fine. Tomcat i cant help it out